# How I can get css property and change the height of html element by javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, responsive-design, css-selectors

I try to create a div element and read height from a CSS selector. finally change the div elemet height by  javascript. When I use `div.style.height ='15px';` work correctly but I want change height dynamically because my CSS class will change by responsive function.

My CSS is:

```
    #indicator {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
    }
```

And I use this code for Script:

```
 div = document.createElement("div");// valve_indicator
 div.style.border = '1px solid #b3280a';

 div.style.height =document.getElementById('indicator').style.height; // instead div.style.height ='15px';
 div.style.width = '15px';
 cell.appendChild(div); // cell is a table cell
```

But `document.getElementById('indicator').style.height` return null.
please help me thanks in advance

Comment: your code is incomplete,please edit your question with full js code

Comment: yes this code use in a for loop i edit it

Comment: you first created div tag but didn't append it to Dom,then you wanted to select it,absolutely the answer in null,must first append to Dom and then select it

Comment: However, you should not enter the # sign in the selector 'getElementById'

Comment: in next line I append it in a table cell  cell.appendChild(div); I edit is

Comment: No,you need to append before select

Comment: I think that the document.getElementById('#indicator').style.height cant return any things the next line work correctly

Comment: Absolutely,because # sign should not enter in selector.you must just enter indicator

Comment: i remove # but not work

Comment: Did you first append the tag?

Comment: I append tag finally same above (question code) when I use div[].style.height ='15px'; work correctly but I want change height dynamically because my CSS class change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem by use this code

```
div.className='indicator';
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `#` in `#indicator`. `getElementById()` doesnt need `#` sign before the id name

```
document.getElementById('indicator').style.height
```

And if you want to dynamically change the `indicator` `height`:

```
let indicator = document.getElementById('indicator');
indicator.addEventListener("change", function(){
    div.style.height = indicator.style.height;
})
```

Comment: Is your `<script>` tag at the end of your `<body>` tag? Your javascript code can not see `indicator div` before its been loaded.

Comment: when I use div[].style.height ='15px'; work correctly but I want change height dynamically because my CSS class is dynamic

Comment: I edited the question for dynamic change. This code should work if you are using `script` tag properly. Hope this helps.